# concurrent merkle tree doc unclear

Tags: validator, solana-test-validator

I've recently started getting interested into the solana bc and its ecosystem, but i find the current doc very unclear and im looking for someone who could explain to me the inner workings of concurrent merkle trees.
It is briefly explained here: https://spl.solana.com/account-compression/concepts

But I dont understand the XOR usage, explained with this example:

```
To swap the nodes when adding a new leaf in the second tree we do the following:

Take XOR of the leaf indices of the change log path and the new leaf in base 2
The depth at which you have to make the swap is the number of leading zeroes in the result(we also add one to it because the swap node is one below the intersection node)
At that depth change the node in the proof to the node in the changelog
Example with the previous trees:

             2   1
Changelog: [X5',X2']
New Leaf: X6'' at leaf index 2

                         2   1
Old proof for new leaf: [X7,X2]

1 XOR 2 = 001 XOR 010 = 011 (no leading zeroes)
depth to swap at = 0 + 1 = 1

                          2   1
New proof for new leaf: [X7,X2']

Note: We use XOR here because changelogs can get large as there can be many concurrent writes so using XOR is more efficient than a simple array search algorithm.
```

but i dont get why XOR is used here, how its supposed to work and how can it work if the tree depth is > 2 because as of my knowledge you cant XOR with 3 inputs.

Im open to an answer from anyone who could have a clue or a documentation/implementation that could help me!

Best